# Making a Many2many field invisible (ODOO 12)

Tags: xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i'm working on odoo 12 (python 3.6) and i'm trying to inherit from several modules to build my own module for Real estate management , Now i'm inheriting from product.template and i want some fields to be invisible , i have a problem with a many2many field (taxes_id from product.template) 
i tried this but it didn't work :

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_gesimmo">
    <field name="name">Product</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='taxes_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Thank you =)**

Comment: It's is probably the wrong view. Can you add the surrounding `record` values (model, id, fields). There is no need for more xpath values.

Comment: `<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_gesimmo">
      <field name="name">Product</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">`

Comment: the error :  ` "taxes_id" field doesn't exist  `

Comment: Are you sure, that module `account` is installed and in the dependencies of your module?

Comment: i tried it and it worked but i have another record with **ref=product.product_template_only_form_view**  that contains some other fields i made them inivsible and they're not invisible anymore when i Added the second record containig a different **ref :account.prodyct_template_form_view**

Comment: `<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>`